# Add columns for missing dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the column labels are dates for a specific period like this:

```
30.okt  2.nov   3.nov   4.nov
-------------------------------
123   |  12  |   23   |  43   |
```

As you can see, the weekends are not included in the dataframe. I need to add columns for the missing days of the weekend and replicate the data from the previous column. My desired output should look like this:

```
30.okt   31.okt   1.nov   2.nov   3.nov  4.nov
--------------------------------------------------
123    |  123   |  123  |  12   |   23   |  43   |
```

I have tried several approaches with pandas, but cannot seem to get it right. Does anyone have any tips to how to solve this easily? Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is your `locale`? `de_DE`?

Comment: My locale is nb_NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import locale

df = pd.DataFrame({'30.okt': [123], '2.nov': [12], '3.nov': [23], '4.nov': [43]})

# The pain...
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF-8')  # Linux
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'German')  # Windows

dti = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%d.%b')
dti = pd.date_range(dti.min(), dti.max(), freq='D')
df = df.reindex(columns=dti.strftime('%-d.%b').str.lower()).ffill(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   30.okt  31.okt  1.nov  2.nov  3.nov  4.nov
0   123.0   123.0  123.0   12.0   23.0   43.0
```

**Update**

Final working code:

```
start_date = '30-10-2020'
end_date = '30-10-2021' 

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'nb_NO')

dti = pd.to_datetime(blnc_df.columns, format='%d.%b')
dti = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')
blnc_df = blnc_df.reindex(columns=dti.strftime('%d.%b').str.lower()).ffill(axis=1)
```

Comment: I changed LC_TIME 'German' to 'Norwegian', and this somewhat works. I get the correct amount of columns, but the dates are suddenly ranging from 1900-01-01 to 1900-12-31, and all the data is now NaN.

Comment: Don't forget the `.strftime('%-d.%b').str.lower()` when you `reindex`.

Comment: start_date = '2020-10-30'
end_date = '2021-10-30'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'nb_NO')

dti = pd.to_datetime(blnc_df.columns, format='%d.%b')
dti = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')
blnc_df = blnc_df.reindex(columns=dti.strftime('%-d.%b').str.lower()).ffill(axis=1)

This gets me the correct amount of columns with correct dates, but the data is gone.

Comment: changing strftime('%-d.%b') to strftime('%d.%b') gets me the data, but the ffill() seems to be filling columns it shouldnt. Removing ffill() shows that some of the data that was in the original dataframe is there, while some of it is now NaN. 30.okt is there for example, but 1-08 okt is not. Every NaN cell is therefore getting filled with the 30.okt data

Comment: You need to use `ffill(axis=1)` and not `fill()`. I don't understand why you remove the `-` in `'%-d.%b'` if your dataframe contains `1.okt` and not `01.okt`

Comment: I am using  ffill(axis=1)  . I just tried to remove the  -  to see what happened, and the columns are named correctly. With the  -  i got timestamps included in the column labels.  And when not including  ffill(axis=1)  at all, the dataframe included some data, but not all of it

Comment: I managed to figure it out by changing the column labels to have `01.okt` format by doing this: `for item in blnc_df.columns:
    if len(item) < 6:
        new_item = '0' + item
        blnc_df.rename(columns={item: new_item}, inplace=True)` Then this code: `start_date = '30-10-2020'
end_date = '30-10-2021'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'nb_NO')

dti = pd.to_datetime(blnc_df.columns, format='%d.%b')
dti = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')
blnc_df = blnc_df.reindex(columns=dti.strftime('%d.%b').str.lower()).ffill(axis=1)
` got me the data i was looking for.

Comment: I updated my answer with your code. Just a magical tip to avoid your loop `blnc_df.columns = blnc_df.columns.str.zfill(6)` :)

Comment: I suspected that it wasnt a great solution! This looks much better :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Setup the base dataframe with missing weekend.

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'10-29-2020': {'a':10},
        '11-01-2020': {'a':16},
        '11-02-2020': {'a':18}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

df
Out[2]: 
   10-29-2020  11-01-2020  11-02-2020
a          10          16          18
```

Transpose to make the dates on the index to later use reindex.

```
df = df.T

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
date_range = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='1d')
date_range

Out[5]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2020-10-29', '2020-10-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-01',
               '2020-11-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Reindex the index with date_range and you will get NaN values on the missing dates, so use ffill() (forward fill to fill them up).

```
df = df.reindex(date_range)

df = df.ffill()

df
Out[7]: 
               a
2020-10-29  10.0
2020-10-30  10.0
2020-10-31  10.0
2020-11-01  16.0
2020-11-02  18.0
```

And transpose.

```
df.T
Out[8]: 
   2020-10-29  2020-10-30  2020-10-31  2020-11-01  2020-11-02
a        10.0        10.0        10.0        16.0        18.0
```

Comment: The format of the date colum labels are like this "31.okt" tho, and they will always be like that since i am originally reading the dataframe from an excel document.

Comment: I don't know about other language localizations and pandas datetime objects. I would suggest writing a function that transforms all of the date strings from the local format to something close to the ISO format and then it can be accepted by pd.to_datetime(). 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Its a lot to do because the date given isn't in a format that Datetime likes. This reads the data into a Series. Converts the given date. Re does the columns/indices. Fills the missing values. Converts the date back to the desired format.

```
import pandas as pd

switcher1 = {
    'jan': 1,
    'feb': 2,
    'mar': 3,
    'apr': 4,
    'mai': 5,
    'jun': 6,
    'jul': 7,
    'aug': 8,
    'sep': 9,
    'okt': 10,
    'nov': 11,
    'dez': 12
}

switcher2 = {
    1: 'jan',
    2: 'feb',
    3: 'mar',
    4: 'apr',
    5: 'mar',
    6: 'jun',
    7: 'jul',
    8: 'aug',
    9: 'sep',
    10: 'okt',
    11: 'nov',
    12: 'dez'
}

def default():
    return "Incorrect day"

def datetime(x):
    date,month = x.split('.')
    month = switcher1.get(month,default())
    return str(month)+'-'+str(date)+'-2022'

def datetime_rev(x):
    x = x.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    month,date,year = x.split('-')
    month = int(month)
    month = switcher2.get(month,default())
    return str(date)+'.'+str(month)

s = pd.Series({'30.okt': 123,
               '2.nov': 12,
               '3.nov': 13,
               '4.nov': 43})
s.index = s.index.to_series().apply(datetime)
idx = pd.date_range(s.index[0],s.index[-1])
s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)
s = s.reindex(idx).ffill()
s.index = s.index.to_series().apply(datetime_rev)
print(s)
```